# Update the folder of GIT with the latest values

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

```
    gitclone: {
      autojqm: {
        options: {
          repository: "https://github.com/imaginethepoet/autojqm"
          branch: "master"
          directory: "repo"
        }
      },
      otherrepo: {
        options: {
          repository: "https://example.com/anotherrepository"
          branch: "master"
          directory: "anotherfolder"
        }
      }
    }

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-git');

    grunt.task.registerTask('gitclone', function() {
        if (this.name=="gitclone"){
            grunt.log.writeln("Hurray");
            gitmerge: {
                your_target: {
                    options: {
                        repository: "https://github.com/imaginethepoet/autojqm"
                        branch :"master"
                        directory:"anotherfolder"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            grunt.log.writeln("OOps");
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('default', ['gitclone']);
```

I am trying to access the folder which is already pulled from GIT, and I am just trying to override that folder with the newer values which have been added.
But I am not unable to get my folder up to date. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: So what do you mean with "override that folder with the newer values which have been added"? Git pull?

Comment: @RemcoHaszing: For Example I clone the git project using gitclone, now if I am having any changes in my GIT then it should get reflected into my already cloned folder. And I need some callback functions on success and on failure...

Comment: @RemcoHaszing: Have u understand my requirement

Comment: No I don't. It seems you are trying to do something unusual now and the question has been changed to it no longer reflects the original question.

Comment: You don't just change a question, buddy...

Answer (score 1):

Just add another target. The following example is plain old JavaScript, but I'm sure you can change it to coffee:

```
gitclone: {
  autojqm: {
    options: {
      repository: "https://github.com/imaginethepoet/autojqm"
      branch: "master"
      directory: "repo"
    }
  },
  otherrepo: {
    options: {
      repository: "https://example.com/anotherrepository"
      branch: "master"
      directory: "anotherfolder"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Changed the question and need some help. Could you please help me out.